# Blend Issue: "Edit Template > Edit a Copy" unavailable for a control when in PopUp

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

Is this a known issue? I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Popup>
        <Slider />
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

I try to edit the ControlTemplate of the Slider by using Blend and right-clicking on the Slider > Edit Template > Edit a Copy. However this option is gray (unavailable).

Thanks,

Kiril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the Popup is closed by default and hence children have no templates applied.

What you want to do is select the popup and check the "IsOpen" property, you'll then be able to edit a copy of the slider.

Hope this helps.